# Functional Link Neural Network use Legendre Polynomial

Tags: matlab

How can I apply the Functional Link Neural Network (Legendre Polynomial) with 4 inputs, namely training data, target training, testing data, and target testing for a microarray. I'm working on my final assignment and don't understand the application of the polynomial to code in Matlab.

Comment: Hi, can you please share what you've already attempted? Do you have any code you tried that didn't work? You'll have to explain what context you are referring to with "microarray". Is this biological data of some kind?

Comment: yes, data biological.